# Rails: Add Prices for Total Sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My **Order** model has_many **Sales**. Sales contains the column "price" and Order the column "totalprice".

A typical Order looks like this:

**Order** record:

-> Sale ID:1, price:5

-> Sale ID:2, price:5

-> Sale ID:3, price:5

Now I want to save the prices from the sales to the order model (should be totalprice=15 in this case). In my Sale Model I've got the following:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  before_create :totalprice

  def totalprice
    @sales.each_with_index do |s, index|
     @totalprice += s.price
    end
   @totalprice = @order.totalprice
  end
```

So, I want to loop through the sales and add the prices. The result should be saved to Order.totalprice.

What would be your approach? I even can't get anything saved to the table and get several (different) errors. So I guess my approach is wrong from the ground up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the model above not be the `Order` not the sale?

Comment: You can replace this code with: `def totalprice sales.map(&:price).reduce(:+) end`

Comment: As mentioned by ConnorCMcKee, you are trying to save data (the sum of Sales) in a column of Order - this is called denormalizing the data.  In other words, you are storing a copy of data in one place, that is already available and canonical in another.
Also what you refer to as @sales in the model Sale, which j-dexx mentioned might be a typo (Sale vs Order for the model in your question).  Even if it were correctly the model Order, the instance variable is not the same as sales (the model method provided by Rails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the sum of all the prices of sale items in an order, You can do this in order model

```
def total_price
  sales.to_a.sum { |item| item.price }
end
```

You can get the total price by calling @order.total_price on an instance of order model

Answer (score 4):

There is [an ActiveRecord method called sum](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum) which is likely what you should use. For instance, if your relationships are established, you could simply write a line like this to get the total price:

```
@order_instance.sales.sum( :price )
```

Rather than making this an actual column in your database (I generally consider it to be a no-no, persisting derived fields back into the records), I would recommend creating an instance method containing the above code. So, in the Order model:

```
def totalprice
  self.sales.sum( :price )
end
```

This would allow you to always access the appropriate value, and remove the headache of updating the record every time a Sale object is added, deleted, or updated.

**Addendum:**

If you're concerned about making multiple redundant queries, or about the underlying data being changed as you work with an Order, you might want to extract the query into an instance variable as well, so that it only runs once:

```
def totalprice
  @total_price ||= self.sales.sum( :price )
end
```

Comment: Cool, didn't knew that Rails offers a AR method for that. I'm getting this error when trying to use your solution: 

`PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("sales"."price") FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."orde...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT SUM("sales"."price") FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."order_id" = $1`